# loop synthesis vhdl

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, process

Suppose we have an iterative algorithm like:

```
r(j) := f(r(j-1))
r(0) := value
```

And that vhdl i implemened a process for such algorithms (assuming a bit of pseudocode...)

```
process(x) is
  variable r := x;
  variable k := 0;
begin
  while(k < MAX) loop
    r := f(r); -- f( ) could be a vhdl function
    k := k + 1;
  end loop;
  y <= r; -- y is the output of the entity that embodies this process
end process;
```

Would the synthesis result in a cascade of `f` logic without pipelining?

Update...

I think i could write something equivalent with a `for ... generate`
would that make some difference in synthesis terms?

Comment: Yes. Update .... and No. (Probably). Some synthesis tools may have trouble synthesising one form, though you will most likely get an equally large and slow result either way.

Comment: How could be designed an iterative algorithm? I mean you said (a priori and of course you're right) that that design is gonna be large and slow. Ok but are there better way for such design (in general)? I suppose the answer depends how the recursion/iteration is formulated.

Comment: One more think... to the purpose of simulation (but i think it is different by simulating a real netlist) would be y updated at every clock cycle?

Comment: No. See your sensitivity list. Y will be updated every time an event happens on X.

Comment: but the stuff inside the loop that one is executed in the same clock cycle? this is because i have variable assignment, what i meant is that y at the end of the process will be assigned to the last value the loop computes, isn't?

Comment: What clock cycle? What clock? Hint : make a simple function f. Say, f(r) = r+1. And try it. In both process and generate form.

Answer (score 2):

Your code cannot be synthesised by the logic synthesizers I know. While loops and for loops are unrolled by the synthesizer and must thus have constant bounds. If you want the result to be combinatorial, use a for loop instead:

```
process(x)
  variable r: <r-type> := x;
begin
  for k in 0 to MAX - 1 loop
    r := f(r);
  end loop;
  y <= r; -- y is the output of the entity that embodies this process
end process;
```

Note that you can indeed do the same with a `generate` statement, the synthesis result would be exactly the same:

```
type r_array is array(0 to MAX) of <r-type>;
...
g: for k in 1 to MAX generate
  r(k) <= f(r(k - 1));
end generate g;
r(0) <= x;
y    <= r(MAX);
```

If you want a sequential result, processing one iteration per clock cycle, use something like:

```
process(clock)
  variable r: <r-type>;
  variable k: natural range 0 to MAX;
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    if reset = '1' then
      k    := MAX;
      done <= '0';
    else
      if start = '1' then
        r    := x;
        k    := 0;
        done <= '0';
      end if;
      if k = MAX then
        done <= '1';
        y    <= r; -- y is the output of the entity that embodies this process
      else
        r := f(r);
        k := k + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: What's the difference between your first code snippet and the mine? Other than the use of a "for" instead of a "while" i don't see the difference.

Comment: The condition of your `while` loop is not static, it depends on a variable `k`. The synthesizer is not smart enough to analyse the body of the loop and discover how many iterations will be needed. In a `for` loop the index is a locally declared constant that cannot be modified in the loop body. So, if the bounds are constant and there are not `next` or `exit` statements in the loop body, the synthesizer can statically know how many iterations are needed.

Comment: Ah ok (i was using pseudocode anyway so i didn't focused much on the all the details on the variable itself), but thank you.